# Ruby on Rails, image link sizing

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, image

I have two images as links on a page. Problem is they are both different sizes. Is there an easy way to resize the images here?

```
  <div class="col-sm-4"><%= link_to image_tag("image1.jpg"), {:controller => 'customers', :action => "new" } %>

    <h3>BOOK A TOUR</H3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <%= link_to image_tag("image2.jpg"), {:controller => 'tours', :action => "index" } %>

    <h3>VIEW TOURS</H3>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: you can use css to set the image size. but note that you can loose the image quality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set image size with `size` property. Let's assume your images are 100 pixels wide and 20 pixels tall. Then you would specify it like this:

```
image_tag("image1.jpg", size: "100x20")

# Generates
# => <img src="/assets/image1.jpg" width="100" height="20" alt="" />
```

And your link code would be:

```
link_to image_tag("image1.jpg", size: "100x20"), {:controller => 'customers', :action => "new" }
```

PS. Consider using `alt` attribute in your images.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Why is alt important?

Comment: It is [considered required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359920/is-it-necessary-to-include-alt-in-images) in < HTML5. Also, it is good for non visual readers.